# Log-in leads to page refreshing

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

So I've set up a page which allows the user to either log-in or register. The registration works fine though the log-in just refreshes the page when correct log-in information is entered and when I enter incorrect log-in information it redirects to login.php with no errors being displayed. I've tried deleting my cookies etc that seem to solve other peoples issues though it's clear it's something deeper.

Log-in form (index.php):

```
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="POST" role="search" action="pages/login.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Login</button>
                </form>
```

Register form (index.php):

```
                    <form method="POST" class="form-signin" action="functions/register.php">
                            <h3 class="text-center">Signup Here!</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname"placeholder="First Name"class="form-control" required>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname"placeholder="Last Name"class="form-control" required>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username"class="form-control" required>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"class="form-control" required>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                        <input type="submit" value="Signup" class="btn btn-success" style="width:100%;">
                    </form>
```

Log-in.php:

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    include '../functions/db.php';

// Escape email to protect against SQL injections
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tbluser WHERE email='$email'");

if ( $result->num_rows == 0 ){ // User doesn't exist
    $_SESSION['message'] = "User with that email doesn't exist!";

}
else { // User exists
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ( password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password']) ) {

    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['email'];
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $user['first_name'];
    $_SESSION['last_name'] = $user['last_name'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user['user_name'];
    $_SESSION['user_Id'] = $user['user_Id'];


    // This is how we'll know the user is logged in
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

    header("location: home.php");
}
else{

   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
   $mysqli->close();
   die();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: So What's your problem now ?  You don't want it to refresh ?

Comment: When I click log-in I want it to go to login.php and process the data and log me into my site. At the moment it just refreshes the page.

Comment: First make sure the file name for login is actually login.php and its in pages folder because that is what you mentioned in login form action.If you are made it correctly comment out everything in login.php just try to echo the data that you got from previous page I.e password and email after that remove comments and try to debug